# sql exception errors

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i am trying to execute a sql command from a java program..i dont have any errors regarding this code..but i am facing connection refusals from the database..

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DBCreateTable
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        DriverManager.registerDriver (new Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
              "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","lms","abc");
        Statement stmt=con.CreateStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("create table emp(eno number(5),name varchar2(20))");
    }
}
```

the errors encountered are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=185599488)(ERR=12505)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12505)(EMFI=4))))
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:404)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.ja
va:468)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
        at DBCreateTable.main(DBCreateTable.java:7)
```

In my sql commands i have done the following..

```
    SQL> connect system/tiger;
    SQL> create user lms identified by abc;
    SQL> grant connect,resource to lms;
```

and plz tell me what is scott tiger..i am messing a lot there..what users are there..what to unlock and how?? plz thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","lms","abc");
```

change it to

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:xe","lms","abc");
```

For more information you can see

```
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC
```

Another change is needed

```
stmt.executeUpdate("create table emp(eno number(5),name varchar2(20))");
```

change to

```
stmt.executeUpdate("create table emp(eno number(5),name varchar2(20));");
```

Comment: i changed it to what you said...i still get an error.. Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "//host:port/service_name"

Comment: try removing the @ symbol Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521:xe","lms","abc");

Comment: still getting some errors...Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)

Comment: stmt.executeUpdate("create table emp(eno number(5),name varchar2(20))"); change this to stmt.executeUpdate("create table emp(eno number(5),name varchar2(20));");

Comment: yeah i had already changed it the first time..but still i am getting the same error..i guess the problem is with the database..can you help with that please?

Comment: yes..i can create..check this error out..Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:573)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1891)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java:109
3)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.ja
va:2047)

Comment: as per a website the 00911 error occurs because of these reasons This error occurs when you try to use a special character in an SQL statement. If a special character other than $, _, and # is used in the name of a column or table, the name must be enclosed in double quotations.
This error may occur if you've pasted your SQL into your editor from another program. Sometimes there are non-printable characters that may be present. In this case, you should try retyping your SQL statement and then re-execute it.

Comment: try to print the con and stmt and see whether it gives logical address or null

Comment: hey friend it printed the following stuff.. oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection@79edfe
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement@723704

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8380/discussion-between-chandra-sekhar-and-user667405)

Comment: please see my question it is similar to this only https://stackoverflow.com/q/45284753/6303688

Answer (score 1):

Probably your oracle services are stopped. scott/tiger is one of default username password in oracle. You should use your try/catch in your code.

Comment: how do i know if my oracle services are stopped?

Comment: type "services.msc" in run , if you are using Windows system, there you can see your all running services. you can find oracle service there

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what the error description says:

```
>oerr ora 12505
12505, 00000, "TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"
// *Cause:  The listener received a request to establish a connection to a
// database or other service. The connect descriptor received by the listener
// specified a SID for an instance (usually a database instance) that either
// has not yet dynamically registered with the listener or has not been
// statically configured for the listener. This may be a temporary condition
// such as after the listener has started, but before the database instance
// has registered with the listener.
// *Action:
//  - Wait a moment and try to connect a second time.
//  - Check which instances are currently known by the listener by executing:
//    lsnrctl services <listener name>
//  - Check that the SID parameter in the connect descriptor specifies
//    an instance known by the listener.
//  - Check for an event in the listener.log file.
```

Comment: how am i suppposed to troubleshoot this

Answer (score 0):

The other problem is that you might have older drivers in the class path (So make sure you don't have classes111.jar or something older in runtime classpath).

Make sure you have the correct driver (thin or oci) in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "lms", "abc");
```