# Connection refused error in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a beginner in Oracle 10g. I have tried to connect with an Oracle 10g database. Here is my code:

```
package com.lara;

import java.sql.*;
class X1{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","scott","tiger1");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
String sql="Create table  emp(Sno int,name Varchar(90),age int)";
stmt.execute(sql);
}
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=169870080)(ERR=12505)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12505)(EMFI=4))))
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:404)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:468)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.lara.X1.main(X1.java:7)
```

Comment: It's not recognizing the SID. Can you connect OK with SQL*Plus? See [https://forums.oracle.com/thread/433363](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/433363)

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511149/sql-exception-errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511149/sql-exception-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a firewall issue. Turn off the firewall or open port 1521.